# dbt documentation resize and align an image (markdown)

Tags: html, css, markdown, dbt

I've created documentation on a dbt project, overwriting the standard documentation overview with the following;

```
{% docs __overview__ %}
...
![ImageName](https://ImageLink)
{% enddocs %}
```

I've tried to use embedded html to resize the image with a fixed height and align it, this works when previewed in Visual Studio Code, but when surfaced locally in dbt docs it just shows the html code instead.

```
<img  src="https://ImageLink" height="50" align="Left" />
```

I've also tried to reference a CSS, to reference the CSS I have the following in index.html

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mystylesheet.css" />
...
</head>
```

side note (anyone know where you can edit this once instead of every time you compile docs?

Then in the markdown I have

```
![ImageName](https://ImageLink#ImageName)
```

and in the css

```
.img[alt=ImageName] { float: left; }
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:  *side note (anyone know where you can edit this once instead of every time you compile docs?* you need to adjust the `index.html` file within the dbt package.

Each time you run `dbt docs generate` it copies the `index.html` folder from the dbt package.  If you're in a virtual environment, the file path would be similar to `~\dbt_project_dir\venv\Lib\site-packages\dbt\include\index.html`

Before doing that, however, you'll want to let dbt know that there is a directory with files in it that you'd like to include.  Following the pattern described [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/description): you want to configure your dbt_project.yml with `asset-paths: ["assets"]`.  Once you do that, then you can edit the aforementioned `index.html` file with a line similar to the below:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='./assets/yourcssstyles.css' />
```